# AD Account Keeps Locking out

Tags: active-directory

We have a GPO that states if a user that unsuccessful logs on more than 3 times to lock the account for 30mins
We have a single user who keeps getting locked out and there are no services, scheduled tasks running under her account.

Audit Log

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       user@domain.local
    Account Domain:     

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xc000006d
    Sub Status:     0xc000006a

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   Business-0005
    Source Network Address: 192.168.89.115
    Source Port:        52399

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you know where the lockout's coming from, examine the logs on that machine. `Workstation Name:   Business-0005
    Source Network Address: 192.168.89.115`

Comment: Did you read the part indicating a workstation name and IP? That should help you to "nail down" what happens here.

Comment: Does the IP resolve to a mobile device or somebody's workstation?

Comment: If you shut that machine down does she keep getting locked out?

Comment: Ok, it look like its Oulook, (user can access email fine, any way to drill into outlook logs?)

Comment: Might just be a (bad) cached logon. Can you open Credential Vault and delete the corresponding identities?

Comment: Email? Really? huh.

Answer (score 2):

The log posted provides you an IP address. This could be the user's machine, their phone or tablet, or another user's machine that is  logging in with the wrong ID. Often times I've found it's a phone or tablet, a user changed their domain password but haven't updated their email apps, thus causing repetitive lockouts.

This isn't an interactive logon but a network request, so that user is likely trying to authenticate remotely and login directly to a machine. Hard to say what service exactly, email is most common.